# Multiclass Classification Evaluator in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
inputneurons = len(pipe_df.columns)
nn = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(layers = [inputneurons,20,2])
nn_model = nn.fit(train_data)
results = nn_model.transform(test_data)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
mlp_accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(results)
```

and when run it, shows errors ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     23 evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
     24 
---> 25 mlp_accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(results)
     26 
     27

and I tried BinaryClassificationEvaluator but it does't work as well..
Is anyone know whats wrong here? I am new to PySpark...